# Firebase chat i can't delete empty text

Tags: android, firebase

When I click on " ENTER "in edittext and press button SendMessage, on the server it is saved" \n " and is displayed in the application just as a blank message. Also when I typed the text and pressed the button several times " ENTER "on the server it is saved" hello!!!\n\n\n\n\n\n \ n". I dont know how decide this problem.
[image: Screenshot]

My xml code

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/sendmsg"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imgsend"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/msgsend"
        />

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/messageReceiver"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner2"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:text="A"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#000"
        tools:ignore="RtlCompat" />
```

Fragment from ChatActivity

```
 public void onClick(View view) {
            if(sendMsg.getText().toString().isEmpty())
                Toast.makeText(ChatActivity.this, "Please enter search query", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            else{
                String message = sendMsg.getText().toString();
                InboxObject ib = new InboxObject();
                Message m = new Message();
                m.setMessage(message);
                m.setCreatedAt(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()));
                m.setImageUrl("");
                m.setSender_uid(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());
                m.setReceiver_uid(uid);
                sendMsg.setText("");


                String key = f_database.child("users").child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("inbox").child(uid).child("messages").push().getKey();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply **.trim()** method on edittext:

```
if(sendMsg.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()){
   //Alert
 }else{
      String message = sendMsg.getText().toString().trim();
 }
```